# How to determine the maximum possible Threads and Blocks for a memory-heavy CUDA application?

Tags: c, linux, cuda

I'm trying to find the optimal value of threads and blocks for my application. Therefore I wrote a small suit to run possible combinations of threadcount, blocksize and gridsize. The task I'm working with, is not parallelizable, so every thread is computing its unique problem and needs read and write access to a unique chunk of global memory for it. I also had to increase cudaLimitStackSize for my kernel to run.
I'm running into problems when I try to calculate the maximum number of threads I can run at once. My refined approach(thanks to Robert Crovella) is

```
threads = (freememory*0.9)/memoryperthread
```

where `freememory` is aquired from `cudaMemGetInfo` and `memoryperthread` is the global memory requirement for one thread. Even if I decrease the constant factor, I still encounter  "unspecified launch failure", which I can't debug because the debugger fails with `Error: Internal error reported by CUDA debugger API (error=1). The application cannot be further debugged.`. Depending on the settings this error 
I'm also encountering a problem when I try different blocksizes. Any blocksize larger than 512 threads yields "too many resources requested for launch". As Robert Crovella pointed out, this may be a problem of my kernel occupying to many registers(63 as reported by -Xptxas="-v"). Since blocks can be spread across several multiProcessorCount, I safly can't find any limitation that would suddenly hit with a blocksize of 1024.

My code runs fine for small values of threads and blocks, but I seem to be unable to compute the maximum numbers I could run at the same time. Is there any way to properly compute those or do I need to do it empirical?

I know that memory heavy tasks aren't optimal for CUDA.
My device is a GTX480 with Compute Capability 2.0. For now I'm stuck with `CUDA Driver Version = 6.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 5.0`.
I do compile with `-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20` to enfore the Compute Capability.

Update: **Most of the aforementioned problems went away after updating the runtime to 6.5**. I will leave this post the way it is, since I mention the errors I encountered and people may stumble up on it when searching for their error. To solve the problem with large blocksizes I had to reduce the registers per thread(-maxrregcount).

Comment: Are you aware of `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize()` function shipped with CUDA 6.5 ? As a side note, did you notice that your Driver and Runtime version mismatch?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I have seen it, but I'm not sure if it will work in my case as it has no option for global memory usage. I'm aware of the mismatch, but I'm not the main administrator of the system I'm working with.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem. What I understand is that you have to process a large amount of data and you are hitting the issue that you do not have enough threads for a one-to-one correspondence between threads and data. Of course, your overall `thread` number cannot exceed `2^31-1`. If `totalmemory/memoryperthread > 2^31-1` then you have to increase the amount of processed memory per thread. Furthermore, you say "_calculating the blocksize from this_", but you do not say how.

Comment: Typically, the number of threads per block is an independent variable that you fix at your will, provided to be less then `1024` for a GTX480. This variable is typically tuned to optimize your code in performance.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

> threads = totalmemory/memoryperthread

If your calculation for `memoryperthread` is accurate, this won't work because `totalmemory` is generally not all available.  The amount you can actually allocate is less than this, due to CUDA runtime overhead, allocation granularity, and other factors.  So that is going to fail somehow, but since you've provided no code, it's impossible to say exactly how.  If you were doing all of this allocation from the host e.g. via `cudaMalloc`, then I would expect an error there, not a kernel unspecified launch failure.  But if you are doing in-kernel `malloc` or `new`, then it's possible that you are trying to use a returned null pointer (indicating an allocation failure - ie. out of memory) and that would probably lead to an unspecified launch failure.

> having a blocksize larger than 512 threads yields "too many resources requested for launch".

This is probably either the fact that you are not compiling for a cc2.0 device or else your kernel uses more registers per thread than what can be supported.  Anyway this is certainly a solvable problem.

> So how would one properly calculate the maximum possible threads and blocks for a kernel?

Often, global memory requirements are a function of the *problem*, not of the kernel size.  If your global memory requirements scale up with kernel size, then there is probably some ratio that can be determined based on the "available memory" reported by `cudaMemGetInfo` (e.g. 90%) that should give reasonably safe operation.  But in general, a program is well designed if it is tolerant of allocation failures, and you should at least be checking for these explicitly on host code and device code, rather than depending on "unspecified launch failure" to tell you that something has gone wrong.  That could be any sort of side-effect bug triggered by memory usage, and may not be directly due to an allocation failure.

I would suggest tracking down these issues.  Debug the problem, find the source of the issue.  I think the correct solution will then present itself.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. I was unaware of the limitations on registers and the difference between total memory and free memory. I do compile with `-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 `. I'm aware that I'm using a lot of registers, but I don't see a way to make room on my own other than `blocksize < multiProcessorCount`. I'm already error checking all cuda operations I'm doing in the code, but that doesn't seem to help. The error never occurs with cudaMalloc. I tried computing the maximum number of total threads from freememory. But it still fails.

Comment: unspecified launch failure is something like a seg fault in host code. Your kernel is doing something illegal.  You can debug that.  Try `cuda-memcheck`, or use a cuda debugger, or use printf, or divide and conquer, or what have you. It's difficult to give a complete tutorial on debugging cuda code in a SO question. For the registers per thread issue, you can limit the register usage by the compiler.  Try googling "cuda registers per thread". When I did that, the very first hit would probably be instructive for you.  On SO, if you want help with non-working code, then you should show an MCVE.

Comment: My code is mostly copied from thoroughly tested C code and runs fine with low thread- and block-counts. Limiting the registers further didn't change anything. The debugger still breaks and cuda-memcheck complains about `Invalid __global__ read of size 1` at locations that contain valid code. From my perspective it seems like the problem lies solely in the amount of threads/blocks I launch. I can't find out what is limiting this amount. I will try to do a MCVE.